# How to Seed DB after DontDropDbJustCreateTablesIfModelChanged

Tags: entity-framework-4.1, ef-code-first

Recently I've had my DB rights reduced so that I can't drop and recreate databases. This has led to me using the DontDropDbJustCreateTablesIfModelChanged Database initialisation from nuget.

However I'm now stuck as to how I should seed data as the Seed function is not in the initialisation so I can't override it. This is what I'd like to be able to do.

```
public class MyDBInitialiser : DontDropDbJustCreateTablesIfModelChanged<MyContext>
{
    protected override void Seed(MyContext context)
    {
        base.Seed(context);

        context.Item.Add(new Item() { ItemId = 1, Name = "Item 1"});
        context.Item.Add(new Item() { ItemId = 2, Name = "Item 2"});
        context.Item.Add(new Item() { ItemId = 3, Name = "Item 3"});
    }
}
```

Is there another way of seeding data in this situation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I my projects I split the db initialization from the db seeding. If you use inversion of control, you should be able to do something like this in your composition root (Application_Start if you are consuming the DbContext from a web app):

```
var seeder = ServiceLocatorPattern
    .ServiceProviderLocator.Current.GetService<ISeedDb>();
if (seeder != null) seeder.Seed();
```

The interface:

```
public interface ISeedDb, IDisposable
{
    void Seed();
}
```

A possible implementation:

```
public class MyDbSeeder : ISeedDb
{
    private readonly MyContext _context;

    public MyDbSeeder(MyContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    public void Seed()
    {
        _context.Item.Add(new Item { ItemId = 1, Name = "Item 1" });
        // ... etc
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        _context.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that's got me out of a mental gutter and thinking about the problem in a different way.

Comment: No problem. BTW I have a couple of projects in my github account that can help with the ServiceProviderLocator and ServiceProviderExtension methods I posted above. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

Simply,

```
public class DontDropDbJustCreateTablesIfModelChanged<T>
                    : IDatabaseInitializer<T> where T : DbContext
{
    private EdmMetadata _edmMetaData;

    public void InitializeDatabase(T context)
    {
        ObjectContext objectContext =
                ((IObjectContextAdapter)context).ObjectContext;

        string modelHash = GetModelHash(objectContext);

        if (CompatibleWithModel(modelHash, context, objectContext))
            return;

        DeleteExistingTables(objectContext);
        CreateTables(objectContext);

        SaveModelHashToDatabase(context, modelHash, objectContext);
        Seed(context);
    }

    protected virtual void Seed(T context) { }

    private void SaveModelHashToDatabase(T context, string modelHash,
                                            ObjectContext objectContext)
    {
        if (_edmMetaData != null) objectContext.Detach(_edmMetaData);

        _edmMetaData = new EdmMetadata();
        context.Set<EdmMetadata>().Add(_edmMetaData);

        _edmMetaData.ModelHash = modelHash;
        context.SaveChanges();
    }

    private void CreateTables(ObjectContext objectContext)
    {
        string dataBaseCreateScript =
            objectContext.CreateDatabaseScript();
        objectContext.ExecuteStoreCommand(dataBaseCreateScript);
    }

    private void DeleteExistingTables(ObjectContext objectContext)
    {
        objectContext.ExecuteStoreCommand(Dropallconstraintsscript);
        objectContext.ExecuteStoreCommand(Deletealltablesscript);
    }

    private string GetModelHash(ObjectContext context)
    {
        var csdlXmlString = GetCsdlXmlString(context).ToString();
        return ComputeSha256Hash(csdlXmlString);
    }

    private bool CompatibleWithModel(string modelHash, DbContext context,
                                        ObjectContext objectContext)
    {
        var isEdmMetaDataInStore =
            objectContext.ExecuteStoreQuery<int>(LookupEdmMetaDataTable)
            .FirstOrDefault();

        if (isEdmMetaDataInStore == 1)
        {
            _edmMetaData = context.Set<EdmMetadata>().FirstOrDefault();
            if (_edmMetaData != null)
            {
                return modelHash == _edmMetaData.ModelHash;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    private string GetCsdlXmlString(ObjectContext context)
    {
        if (context != null)
        {
            var entityContainerList = context.MetadataWorkspace
                .GetItems<EntityContainer>(DataSpace.SSpace);

            if (entityContainerList != null)
            {
                var entityContainer = entityContainerList.FirstOrDefault();
                var generator =
                    new EntityModelSchemaGenerator(entityContainer);
                var stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
                var xmlWRiter = XmlWriter.Create(stringBuilder);
                generator.GenerateMetadata();
                generator.WriteModelSchema(xmlWRiter);
                xmlWRiter.Flush();
                return stringBuilder.ToString();
            }
        }
        return string.Empty;
    }

    private static string ComputeSha256Hash(string input)
    {
        byte[] buffer = new SHA256Managed()
            .ComputeHash(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(input));

        var builder = new StringBuilder(buffer.Length * 2);
        foreach (byte num in buffer)
        {
            builder.Append(num.ToString("X2",
                CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
        }
        return builder.ToString();
    }

    private const string Dropallconstraintsscript =
        @"select  
        'ALTER TABLE ' + so.table_name + ' DROP CONSTRAINT ' 
        + so.constraint_name  
        from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS so";

    private const string Deletealltablesscript =
        @"declare @cmd varchar(4000)
        declare cmds cursor for 
        Select
            'drop table [' + Table_Name + ']'
        From
            INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES

        open cmds
        while 1=1
        begin
            fetch cmds into @cmd
            if @@fetch_status != 0 break
            print @cmd
            exec(@cmd)
        end
        close cmds
        deallocate cmds";

    private const string LookupEdmMetaDataTable =
        @"Select COUNT(*) 
        FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES T 
        Where T.TABLE_NAME = 'EdmMetaData'";
}
```

&

```
public class Population : DontDropDbJustCreateTablesIfModelChanged</* DbContext */>
{
    protected override void Seed(Syndication Context)
    {
        /* Seeding :) */
    }
}
```

&

```
Database.SetInitializer</* DbContext */>(new Population());
```